# Using lapply and maybe for-loop for several data sets with the same structure to extract and calculate values for each data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have a question regarding lapply and for loops.

I have a number of data files which are all structured the same containing values in several columns and are "space delimited".

Can I use a `lapply` command to read the files and afterwards a loop or the function inside the `lapply` to calculate values out of each data set in different steps?

I need to find maxima and minima of values at a range of temperatures and want to create the difference of both values.

The difference I want to save for each data set containing the name of the data set and the resulting value.

When I try it with one data set, it is no problem - my biggest challenge is convert the commands of that single file calculation into a function to be applied in the lapply command. Below are the fragments of code for reading one data set that you might understand what i want to do:

```
    data1<- read.fwf("data1.cur", widths = c(1, 5, 4, 5,4,6,1,5,13,3,34), skip = 1) # necessary because of the space limiting

    data1<- data1[,c(2,4,6,8,9)] # then I select the columns which I need and are resulting of the previous code nor NAs

    colnames(data1) <- c("TempC", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4") # then I give the column names which I deleted in the first code line by skip=1, because they are not usable 

    plot(data1$TempC, data1$value1, type="l") # here I check if everything worked - yes it does 

    max<- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 220 & data1$TempC < 240) # there is the first range where the maximum should occur (there are several maxima in the data1 set but I need that maximum close to 230 degree celsius

    min <- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 390 & data1$TempC < 410) # same for the maximum i search for the minimum at a distinct place around 400 degree celsius

    max_real <- max(max$value1) # select the real max

    min_real <- min(min$value1) # select the real min

    difference <- max_real -min_real # final difference value
```

Here is a single data file (data1) with spaces in between the columns (number of spaces is varying by the length of the values, this is why the read.fwf() command and specific widths are used to read the data:

```
  TEMP    TSUSC     CSUSC NSUSC       BULKS    FERRT    FERRB   TIMEPL_20leer
  26.2     21.3     82.92 0.271      1076.9      0.0      0.0      0     79.0
  27.2     21.7     83.32 0.272      1082.1      0.0      0.0     24    0.770
  32.9     21.8     83.31 0.272      1081.9      0.0      0.0     47    0.000
  40.4     22.4     83.67 0.273      1086.6      0.0      0.0     69    0.000
  48.2     23.3     84.53 0.276      1097.8      0.0      0.0     92        5
  55.5     23.3     84.83 0.277      1101.6      0.0      0.0    115   0/1400
  62.5     25.3     86.89 0.284      1128.5      0.0      0.0    138        2
  68.8     25.0     86.59 0.283      1124.5      0.0      0.0    161        0
  74.8     25.1     86.70 0.283      1126.0      0.0      0.0    183        0
  80.8     25.0     86.78 0.284      1127.0      0.0      0.0    206     0.00
  86.3     26.1     87.91 0.287      1141.7      0.0      0.0    229     0.00
  91.8     26.3     88.05 0.288      1143.5      0.0      0.0    252     0.00
  97.4     27.6     89.44 0.292      1161.5      0.0      0.0    275     0.00
 102.4     27.0     89.03 0.291      1156.2      0.0      0.0    297     0.00
 107.7     27.2     89.17 0.291      1158.1      0.0      0.0    320     0.00
 112.7     28.2     90.13 0.295      1170.5      0.0      0.0    343     0.00
 117.2     28.8     90.69 0.296      1177.8      0.0      0.0    366     0.00
 121.4     28.9     90.70 0.296      1177.9      0.0      0.0    389     0.00
 125.9     28.7     90.42 0.295      1174.2      0.0      0.0    412     0.00
 130.5     29.1     90.93 0.297      1181.0      0.0      0.0    434         
 135.5     28.3     90.09 0.294      1170.0      0.0      0.0    457         
 140.6     28.4     90.07 0.294      1169.8      0.0      0.0    480         
 146.2     29.2     90.95 0.297      1181.2      0.0      0.0    503  177.571
 151.8     29.3     91.10 0.298      1183.2      0.0      0.0    526  292.015
 157.7     29.6     91.08 0.298      1182.9      0.0      0.0    549      174
 163.4     29.7     91.30 0.298      1185.7      0.0      0.0    572     1.00
 168.8     28.9     90.68 0.296      1177.7      0.0      0.0    594       40
 174.2     29.5     91.16 0.298      1183.9      0.0      0.0    617      408
 179.8     29.6     91.17 0.298      1184.0      0.0      0.0    640        0
 185.0     30.5     92.23 0.301      1197.8      0.0      0.0    663    0.000
 190.7     30.8     92.71 0.303      1204.0      0.0      0.0    686    0.000
 195.8     31.3     93.17 0.305      1210.1      0.0      0.0    709        0
 201.0     31.8     93.68 0.306      1216.6      0.0      0.0    732     0.00
 206.2     32.3     94.23 0.308      1223.8      0.0      0.0    755        0
 211.3     33.5     95.51 0.312      1240.4      0.0      0.0    778        0
 216.8     34.3     96.34 0.315      1251.1      0.0      0.0    800        0
 222.6     35.0     97.18 0.318      1262.1      0.0      0.0    823        0
 228.3     35.9     98.20 0.321      1275.3      0.0      0.0    846      0.0
 234.1     36.9     99.40 0.325      1290.9      0.0      0.0    869      0.0
 240.1     37.1     99.53 0.325      1292.6      0.0      0.0    892      0.0
 245.7     36.9     99.24 0.324      1288.9      0.0      0.0    915      0.0
 251.5     36.7     98.96 0.323      1285.2      0.0      0.0    938      0.0
 257.5     36.0     98.15 0.321      1274.6      0.0      0.0    961      0.0
 263.1     35.6     97.50 0.319      1266.2      0.0      0.0    984      0.0
 268.6     35.0     97.04 0.317      1260.2      0.0      0.0   1007      0.0
 274.2     33.4     95.45 0.312      1239.6      0.0      0.0   1030      0.0
 279.5     32.5     94.62 0.309      1228.9      0.0      0.0   1053      0.0
 285.1     31.2     93.36 0.305      1212.5      0.0      0.0   1076         
 290.7     29.1     91.30 0.298      1185.7      0.0      0.0   1100         
 296.0     27.9     89.98 0.294      1168.6      0.0      0.0   1123         
 301.6     25.9     88.12 0.288      1144.4      0.0      0.0   1146         
 307.0     24.2     86.48 0.283      1123.1      0.0      0.0   1169         
 312.1     22.6     85.07 0.278      1104.8      0.0      0.0   1192         
 317.4     21.3     83.75 0.274      1087.6      0.0      0.0   1215         
 322.8     19.5     82.02 0.268      1065.2      0.0      0.0   1238         
 328.2     18.3     80.68 0.264      1047.8      0.0      0.0   1261         
 333.6     16.9     79.22 0.259      1028.8      0.0      0.0   1284         
 339.2     15.6     77.89 0.255      1011.6      0.0      0.0   1307         
 344.7     13.6     76.03 0.248       987.4      0.0      0.0   1330         
 350.4     12.3     74.68 0.244       969.9      0.0      0.0   1353         
 355.8     11.1     73.63 0.241       956.3      0.0      0.0   1376         
 361.5      9.7     72.35 0.236       939.7      0.0      0.0   1399         
 366.7      7.9     70.53 0.231       916.0      0.0      0.0   1422         
 372.4      6.8     69.36 0.227       900.8      0.0      0.0   1446         
 377.6      5.1     67.79 0.222       880.4      0.0      0.0   1469         
 382.8      3.6     66.49 0.217       863.5      0.0      0.0   1492         
 387.7      2.1     64.99 0.212       844.0      0.0      0.0   1516         
 393.2      0.4     63.31 0.207       822.2      0.0      0.0   1539         
 398.7     -0.8     62.12 0.203       806.7      0.0      0.0   1562         
 404.3     -2.1     60.96 0.199       791.6      0.0      0.0   1584         
 409.5     -3.4     59.66 0.195       774.7      0.0      0.0   1608         
 414.7     -4.5     58.41 0.191       758.6      0.0      0.0   1630         
 419.7     -5.5     57.50 0.188       746.7      0.0      0.0   1653         
 424.7     -6.3     56.82 0.186       737.9      0.0      0.0   1676         
 430.2     -7.0     56.06 0.183       728.1      0.0      0.0   1699         
 435.2     -7.7     55.25 0.181       717.5      0.0      0.0   1722         
 440.5     -8.1     54.98 0.180       714.0      0.0      0.0   1745         
 445.8     -8.2     54.96 0.180       713.8      0.0      0.0   1769         
 451.7     -8.1     55.14 0.180       716.1      0.0      0.0   1791         
 457.7     -7.4     55.92 0.183       726.2      0.0      0.0   1814         
 463.0     -6.0     57.24 0.187       743.4      0.0      0.0   1837         
 468.6     -4.0     59.28 0.194       769.8      0.0      0.0   1860         
 474.9     -1.2     62.12 0.203       806.8      0.0      0.0   1883         
 480.2      1.8     65.14 0.213       846.0      0.0      0.0   1906         
 485.6      5.2     68.63 0.224       891.3      0.0      0.0   1929         
 491.0      8.2     71.64 0.234       930.4      0.0      0.0   1952         
 495.8     11.5     74.90 0.245       972.7      0.0      0.0   1975         
 501.2     13.9     77.32 0.253      1004.2      0.0      0.0   1998         
 506.3     15.7     79.14 0.259      1027.8      0.0      0.0   2021         
 511.8     16.6     80.10 0.262      1040.3      0.0      0.0   2044         
 517.5     16.5     80.06 0.262      1039.7      0.0      0.0   2067         
 522.6     15.6     79.22 0.259      1028.8      0.0      0.0   2090         
 527.5     13.8     77.43 0.253      1005.6      0.0      0.0   2113         
 532.4     11.5     75.20 0.246       976.7      0.0      0.0   2135         
 536.9      7.7     71.36 0.233       926.8      0.0      0.0   2158         
 542.4      3.2     66.90 0.219       868.8      0.0      0.0   2181         
 547.6     -2.3     61.53 0.201       799.0      0.0      0.0   2204         
 552.8     -7.6     56.35 0.184       731.9      0.0      0.0   2227         
 558.0    -12.4     51.46 0.168       668.3      0.0      0.0   2250         
 563.2    -17.2     46.85 0.153       608.4      0.0      0.0   2273         
 568.8    -21.7     42.37 0.138       550.3      0.0      0.0   2296         
 574.6    -25.8     38.33 0.125       497.8      0.0      0.0   2319         
 580.2    -31.4     32.76 0.107       425.4      0.0      0.0   2342         
 585.4    -37.2     27.00 0.088       350.6      0.0      0.0   2365         
 590.4    -40.3     23.76 0.078       308.5      0.0      0.0   2387         
 595.4    -42.4     21.63 0.071       280.9      0.0      0.0   2410         
 600.6    -44.3     19.69 0.064       255.7      0.0      0.0   2433         
 605.6    -45.6     18.38 0.060       238.8      0.0      0.0   2456         
 610.9    -46.8     17.30 0.057       224.7      0.0      0.0   2479         
 615.0    -47.8     16.26 0.053       211.2      0.0      0.0   2502         
 620.0    -48.3     15.90 0.052       206.5      0.0      0.0   2525         
 624.4    -49.3     14.97 0.049       194.4      0.0      0.0   2548         
 629.1    -50.1     14.24 0.047       185.0      0.0      0.0   2571         
 634.2    -51.0     13.50 0.044       175.3      0.0      0.0   2594         
 639.5    -51.5     13.18 0.043       171.1      0.0      0.0   2617         
 644.6    -52.4     12.21 0.040       158.6      0.0      0.0   2639         
 649.7    -53.1     11.54 0.038       149.8      0.0      0.0   2662         
 654.7    -53.5     11.16 0.036       144.9      0.0      0.0   2685         
 659.8    -54.6      9.97 0.033       129.5      0.0      0.0   2708         
 664.6    -55.1      9.60 0.031       124.7      0.0      0.0   2731         
 669.4    -55.6      9.12 0.030       118.5      0.0      0.0   2754         
 674.5    -56.2      8.59 0.028       111.5      0.0      0.0   2777         
 679.3    -56.7      7.98 0.026       103.6      0.0      0.0   2800         
 684.4    -57.2      7.45 0.024        96.7      0.0      0.0   2823         
 689.6    -57.8      6.86 0.022        89.1      0.0      0.0   2846         
 695.1    -58.5      6.22 0.020        80.8      0.0      0.0   2869         
 699.3    -59.3      5.53 0.018        71.8      0.0      0.0   2892         
 705.4    -59.7      5.32 0.017        69.0      0.0      0.0   2915         
 706.7    -60.1      4.96 0.016        64.4      0.0      0.0   2938         
 706.0    -60.1      4.94 0.016        64.2      0.0      0.0   2961         
 704.4    -60.1      4.92 0.016        63.9      0.0      0.0   2984         
 702.2    -59.9      5.14 0.017        66.8      0.0      0.0   3007         
 698.9    -59.4      5.64 0.018        73.2      0.0      0.0   3030         
 695.4    -59.0      6.04 0.020        78.4      0.0      0.0   3053         
 691.5    -58.4      6.64 0.022        86.2      0.0      0.0   3076         
 687.0    -57.9      7.03 0.023        91.4      0.0      0.0   3099         
 683.5    -57.0      7.83 0.026       101.7      0.0      0.0   3122         
 679.0    -56.3      8.52 0.028       110.7      0.0      0.0   3145         
 673.9    -55.2      9.58 0.031       124.4      0.0      0.0   3168         
 669.1    -54.0     10.74 0.035       139.5      0.0      0.0   3191         
 664.6    -52.8     12.05 0.039       156.6      0.0      0.0   3214         
 660.1    -51.8     13.17 0.043       171.0      0.0      0.0   3237         
 656.0    -50.4     14.54 0.048       188.8      0.0      0.0   3260         
 651.6    -49.1     15.78 0.052       205.0      0.0      0.0   3283         
 647.8    -47.5     17.37 0.057       225.5      0.0      0.0   3306         
 643.0    -45.5     19.12 0.062       248.3      0.0      0.0   3329         
 638.6    -43.6     20.93 0.068       271.8      0.0      0.0   3351         
 634.2    -41.8     22.57 0.074       293.2      0.0      0.0   3374         
 630.1    -39.5     24.73 0.081       321.2      0.0      0.0   3397         
 625.7    -37.6     26.50 0.087       344.1      0.0      0.0   3420         
 621.0    -35.2     28.95 0.095       375.9      0.0      0.0   3443         
 616.3    -32.6     31.39 0.103       407.6      0.0      0.0   3466         
 612.5    -30.0     33.94 0.111       440.8      0.0      0.0   3489         
 607.8    -27.2     36.75 0.120       477.3      0.0      0.0   3512         
 603.1    -24.0     39.93 0.131       518.6      0.0      0.0   3535         
 598.5    -20.3     43.57 0.142       565.8      0.0      0.0   3558         
 594.1    -16.5     47.38 0.155       615.3      0.0      0.0   3581         
 589.5    -11.1     52.78 0.172       685.5      0.0      0.0   3604         
 585.1     -3.6     60.24 0.197       782.4      0.0      0.0   3626         
 580.5      5.8     69.59 0.227       903.8      0.0      0.0   3649         
 575.8     16.1     79.82 0.261      1036.6      0.0      0.0   3672         
 571.5     25.0     88.73 0.290      1152.3      0.0      0.0   3695         
 566.9     33.8     97.44 0.318      1265.5      0.0      0.0   3718         
 562.0     43.0    106.65 0.349      1385.0      0.0      0.0   3741         
 557.1     53.2    116.72 0.381      1515.9      0.0      0.0   3764         
 551.9     63.8    127.34 0.416      1653.8      0.0      0.0   3787         
 546.7     73.9    137.42 0.449      1784.7      0.0      0.0   3809         
 541.5     83.8    147.30 0.481      1913.0      0.0      0.0   3833         
 536.6     93.6    157.10 0.513      2040.3      0.0      0.0   3855         
 531.7    102.6    166.08 0.543      2156.9      0.0      0.0   3878         
 527.5    111.0    174.46 0.570      2265.8      0.0      0.0   3901         
 522.6    119.5    182.91 0.598      2375.4      0.0      0.0   3924         
 518.1    127.8    191.17 0.625      2482.7      0.0      0.0   3947         
 513.3    137.0    200.36 0.655      2602.1      0.0      0.0   3970         
 507.8    146.5    209.80 0.686      2724.7      0.0      0.0   3994         
 502.7    156.5    219.84 0.718      2855.1      0.0      0.0   4018         
 497.3    165.2    228.50 0.747      2967.6      0.0      0.0   4042         
 492.5    173.1    236.42 0.773      3070.4      0.0      0.0   4066         
 486.8    180.5    243.86 0.797      3167.0      0.0      0.0   4090         
 481.7    189.7    253.04 0.827      3286.2      0.0      0.0   4114         
 476.7    197.0    260.23 0.850      3379.6      0.0      0.0   4138         
 471.3    203.2    266.36 0.871      3459.3      0.0      0.0   4162         
 466.0    208.5    271.60 0.888      3527.3      0.0      0.0   4186         
 460.9    214.4    277.46 0.907      3603.4      0.0      0.0   4210         
 455.6    219.4    282.44 0.923      3668.1      0.0      0.0   4234         
 450.3    224.3    287.36 0.939      3732.0      0.0      0.0   4258         
 445.0    228.1    291.14 0.951      3781.0      0.0      0.0   4282         
 439.4    230.3    293.25 0.958      3808.5      0.0      0.0   4306         
 434.1    234.1    297.02 0.971      3857.3      0.0      0.0   4330         
 428.8    236.1    298.97 0.977      3882.8      0.0      0.0   4354         
 423.5    237.6    300.43 0.982      3901.7      0.0      0.0   4378         
 418.0    238.0    300.82 0.983      3906.8      0.0      0.0   4403         
 412.7    240.2    303.11 0.991      3936.5      0.0      0.0   4427         
 407.7    241.5    304.38 0.995      3953.0      0.0      0.0   4451         
 402.8    241.9    304.78 0.996      3958.2      0.0      0.0   4475         
 397.3    241.6    304.48 0.995      3954.3      0.0      0.0   4499         
 392.4    241.9    304.78 0.996      3958.2      0.0      0.0   4523         
 387.1    241.9    304.68 0.996      3956.9      0.0      0.0   4547         
 381.9    243.2    305.98 1.000      3973.8      0.0      0.0   4571         
 376.5    242.4    305.09 0.997      3962.2      0.0      0.0   4595         
 371.3    243.0    305.60 0.999      3968.8      0.0      0.0   4620         
 365.8    243.3    305.92 1.000      3973.0      0.0      0.0   4644         
 360.4    243.2    305.73 0.999      3970.5      0.0      0.0   4667         
 354.9    242.3    304.88 0.996      3959.5      0.0      0.0   4692         
 348.9    240.6    303.24 0.991      3938.2      0.0      0.0   4716         
 343.8    241.9    304.52 0.995      3954.8      0.0      0.0   4739         
 338.1    240.4    303.04 0.990      3935.6      0.0      0.0   4764         
 332.1    237.3    299.86 0.980      3894.2      0.0      0.0   4788         
 326.8    237.7    300.31 0.981      3900.1      0.0      0.0   4811         
 320.8    236.7    299.15 0.978      3885.1      0.0      0.0   4836         
 314.9    236.2    298.64 0.976      3878.4      0.0      0.0   4859         
 309.5    233.9    296.36 0.969      3848.8      0.0      0.0   4883         
 303.9    233.1    295.53 0.966      3838.0      0.0      0.0   4907         
 298.0    231.6    293.83 0.960      3815.9      0.0      0.0   4931         
 292.4    230.9    293.40 0.959      3810.4      0.0      0.0   4955         
 286.8    228.5    290.78 0.950      3776.4      0.0      0.0   4979         
 281.7    227.0    289.32 0.946      3757.4      0.0      0.0   5002         
 276.2    226.5    288.86 0.944      3751.4      0.0      0.0   5026         
 270.9    225.5    287.80 0.941      3737.6      0.0      0.0   5050         
 265.3    222.1    284.46 0.930      3694.3      0.0      0.0   5074         
 260.0    222.8    285.21 0.932      3704.1      0.0      0.0   5098         
 254.5    219.5    281.88 0.921      3660.8      0.0      0.0   5121         
 248.7    216.8    279.16 0.912      3625.4      0.0      0.0   5145         
 243.4    216.3    278.66 0.911      3619.0      0.0      0.0   5169         
 237.7    217.9    280.31 0.916      3640.4      0.0      0.0   5193         
 231.9    212.7    275.13 0.899      3573.1      0.0      0.0   5217         
 226.4    213.3    275.43 0.900      3577.0      0.0      0.0   5241         
 220.9    208.5    270.69 0.885      3515.4      0.0      0.0   5264         
 215.7    208.5    270.73 0.885      3516.0      0.0      0.0   5288         
 210.0    207.5    269.49 0.881      3499.8      0.0      0.0   5312         
 204.5    206.8    268.74 0.878      3490.2      0.0      0.0   5336         
 198.8    204.3    266.34 0.870      3458.9      0.0      0.0   5360         
 193.4    198.5    260.48 0.851      3382.9      0.0      0.0   5384         
 187.7    202.7    264.58 0.865      3436.1      0.0      0.0   5408         
 182.0    201.6    263.64 0.862      3423.9      0.0      0.0   5431         
 176.9    200.1    262.23 0.857      3405.6      0.0      0.0   5455         
 171.2    196.4    258.52 0.845      3357.4      0.0      0.0   5479         
 166.3    202.2    264.59 0.865      3436.2      0.0      0.0   5503         
 161.2    199.0    261.43 0.854      3395.2      0.0      0.0   5527         
 156.1    192.2    254.32 0.831      3302.8      0.0      0.0   5551         
 150.8    195.8    257.96 0.843      3350.1      0.0      0.0   5575         
 145.9    192.9    255.13 0.834      3313.4      0.0      0.0   5598         
 141.1    194.2    255.91 0.836      3323.5      0.0      0.0   5622         
 136.1    189.1    250.93 0.820      3258.8      0.0      0.0   5646         
 131.0    190.9    252.85 0.826      3283.8      0.0      0.0   5670         
 125.9    187.4    249.32 0.815      3237.9      0.0      0.0   5694         
 121.2    187.4    249.17 0.814      3236.0      0.0      0.0   5718         
 116.4    188.3    250.25 0.818      3250.0      0.0      0.0   5742         
 111.4    184.4    246.32 0.805      3198.9      0.0      0.0   5766         
 106.9    183.7    245.49 0.802      3188.1      0.0      0.0   5790         
 102.1    181.4    243.50 0.796      3162.4      0.0      0.0   5814         
  97.6    181.2    243.32 0.795      3160.0      0.0      0.0   5838         
  92.9    180.9    243.16 0.795      3158.0      0.0      0.0   5862         
  88.4    179.4    241.56 0.789      3137.2      0.0      0.0   5886         
  84.2    185.0    247.29 0.808      3211.6      0.0      0.0   5910         
  79.8    178.9    240.75 0.787      3126.6      0.0      0.0   5934         
  75.6    178.4    240.44 0.786      3122.6      0.0      0.0   5957         
  71.4    179.4    241.48 0.789      3136.1      0.0      0.0   5981         
  67.5    176.1    238.13 0.778      3092.6      0.0      0.0   6005         
  63.8    175.3    237.31 0.776      3081.9      0.0      0.0   6029         
  59.9    175.4    237.26 0.775      3081.3      0.0      0.0   6053         
  56.3    174.9    236.79 0.774      3075.2      0.0      0.0   6077         
  52.9    172.3    234.11 0.765      3040.3      0.0      0.0   6100         
  50.0    175.3    237.08 0.775      3079.0      0.0      0.0   6124         
  47.2    172.4    234.26 0.766      3042.3      0.0      0.0   6148         
  44.3    172.3    234.14 0.765      3040.8      0.0      0.0   6172         
  41.7    171.2    233.04 0.762      3026.5      0.0      0.0   6196         
  39.1    169.9    231.74 0.757      3009.6      0.0      0.0   6220
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your data: `data1` that you have used in order to make the question reproducible.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for the hint - is it now correct? Kind regards, Chris

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Ideally you should put a dataframe or similar object into your question rather than the print version of your data. Like this: df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! Also only include the minimum amount of information in order to illustrate the question. It is not helpful just to include a big dataframe. You can use dput() and edit the output in your console into a sensible format before pasting into your question.

Comment: Dear Peter, the thing with the data frame is problematic - first I thought about it but it would eliminate a part of my question. Eliminating the weird limitors (spaces) inside the raw data frame would suggest that they are not there - but they are - this is why I am more convinced to show the real data structure than the data frame. What do you think? All the best, Chris

Comment: The spaces would be NAs probably but not a problem. However, you have an answer already.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the code you want to apply to each file in a function.

```
do_analaysis <- function(filename) {

  data1<- read.fwf(filename, widths = c(1, 5, 4, 5,4,6,1,5,13,3,34), skip = 1) 
  data1<- data1[,c(2,4,6,8,9)]
  colnames(data1) <- c("TempC", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4") 
  max<- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 220 & data1$TempC < 240)
  min <- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 390 & data1$TempC < 410) 
  max_real <- max(max$value1) 
  min_real <- min(min$value1)
  return(max_real - min_real )
}
```

Gather all the filenames using `list.files`. To identify the files, here you can specify if the files have any specific pattern in them. Let's say you want to apply this to all files that end with `".cur"`.

```
filenames <- list.files('path/to/files/', pattern = '\\.cur', full.names = TRUE)
```

and apply the function using `lapply`/`sapply` :

```
output <- lapply(filenames, do_analaysis)
#output <- sapply(filenames, do_analaysis)
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Shah, thank you so much for your help - it works so nicely !!! Thank you so much! Have a nice weekend, Chris

Answer (score 1):

One can add the code to an anonymous function with `lapply()`, and output the results as a data frame. Here we make 3 copies of the data from the OP, read them and summarise with `lapply()`.

```
theFiles <- list.files("./data","\\.cur")
resultsList <- lapply(theFiles,function(x){
     data1<- read.fwf(paste0("./data/",x), widths = c(1, 5, 4, 5,4,6,1,5,13,3,34), 
                      skip = 1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
     data1<- data1[,c(2,4,6,8,9)] 
     colnames(data1) <- c("TempC", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4") 
     max<- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 220 & data1$TempC < 240) 
     min <- subset(data1,data1$TempC > 390 & data1$TempC < 410) 
     max_real <- max(max$value1) # select the real max
     min_real <- min(min$value1) # select the real min
     difference <- max_real -min_real # final difference value
     data.frame(fileName = x,min_real,max_real,difference)
})

# combine results into single data frame & print
do.call(rbind,resultsList)
```

...and the output:

```
> # combine results into single data frame & print
> do.call(rbind,resultsList)
   fileName min_real max_real difference
1 data1.cur     -3.4    217.9      221.3
2 data2.cur     -3.4    217.9      221.3
3 data3.cur     -3.4    217.9      221.3
>
```